# How do I customize laravel fatal error exception?

Tags: laravel

I wanted to know how do I customize laravel Fatal Error message? I don't like the default one that looks like this

[image: FatalErrorException]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message you're viewing is only visible in the `local` environment. This view is generated by package `filp/whoops` as seen in `composer.json`. When you switch your `.env` file to production (`APP_ENV=production`), this is no longer seen and instead shows a stripped down error page that doesnt give away these debugging details.

If you want to change this for local environment, take a look at your Exceptions Handler's `render` method and you should be able to customize it.

Comment: Oh really? so when I put my project in the world wide web this will not be shown but instead it will show a stripped down error page?

Comment: well yes, you should never be showing debugging information to the end user unless you want them to see it

Comment: oh okay. That gave me so much clarity. I'm over here overthinking this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Side note: You can customize the stripped-down error page, too. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/errors#custom-http-error-pages

Answer (score 1):

In your .env file, updating APP_ENV=production will not render the above error trace.

Some exceptions describe HTTP error codes from the server. For example, this may be a "page not found" error (404), an "unauthorized error" (401) or even a developer generated 500 error.

Laravel makes it easy to display custom error pages for various HTTP status codes. For example, if you wish to customize the error page for 404 HTTP status codes, create a resources/views/errors/404.blade.php. This file will be served on all 404 errors generated by your application. The views within this directory should be named to match the HTTP status code they correspond to.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `try{} catch(){}` block which allows you to detect the type of the error and act accrodingly. In my project, I use my own Exception class that has a standard form. It can be sent to API or view.

Comment: Thanks I will look in to that

Comment: @JayJay123 you can detect the exception in a controller. If it happens, you can return any view you want displaying the error. Let me know, how it works.